# How bad is Puerto Rico for hurricanes in June?

Tags: weather-and-climate, seasonal, natural-disasters, puerto-rico

I'd like to travel to Puerto Rico next June and I heard that around July is the hurricane season.

I already found some pages on the Internet, but cannot decide if these are trustworthy. I found information about that there is only an 8% chance to experience a hurricane, other pages state that there were hurricanes in June for the last years.

So, are there (official) statistics I can trust? Is is safe to travel to Puerto Rico in June? Or should I wait and probably travel in January 2017 (which would be much more expensive)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bulk of hurricanes which effect Puerto Rico are later in the season (August, September, October).  The chance of a June hurricane are fairly slim.

Your best source of historical data would be the National Weather Service's annual Atlantic Hurricane reports which go back 20 years online.  You can see a map of all the storm paths for each year's hurricane season and then read about each specific storm if any effect P.R.

http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/data/tcr/

Personally I wouldn't let the extremely slight risk of a hurricane deter me from visiting P.R. in June.

Answer (score 2):

Puerto Rico has not been hit by a hurricane in quite a few years now and this season seems pretty light so it is unlikely that it will get hit.  It is perfectly safe weatherwise to travel to PR in June.  In fact, the water at the beaches is at its most cristaline and warm during that period.  It is also safer to swim in the northern beaches during June due to the change in the direction of the winds which makes for less waves and undercurrents (although you do have to be vigilant of specific beaches like Jobos Beach in Isabela that are famous for the dangers of their undercurrents).

Expect it to be warm and sunny with a pretty high chance of a 15 to 30 minute shower around 3 pm every afternoon.

One thing you should be more worried about is the crime in the city of San Juan.  It is not terribly dangerous but if you are planning on going out and about the old city or Condado at night, be aware of your surroundings.